# Android Xamarin App works flawlessly up to Android 11.0 (API Level 30) - Instantly crashes (won't even launch) when Target is set to 12.0 (API 31)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

My minimum Android Version is Android 5.0, and Target Android Version is 12.0. I have tested with both Android 12.1 and 13.0 as well, the app crashes instantly with all three. 11.0 and below, all work flawlessly. I have tried all of them with the "Compile using Android Version (Target Framework)" set to Android 11.0, 12.0, and 13.0 all with the same result. All versions even 12.0 and above work without issue in my emulators. The issue is limited to phsyical devices as far as I can tell. This makes it very difficult, well actually impossible to debug, as even launching directly to my physical device over USB in debug, I am not getting any relevant output.

Since the play store has increased the minimum targeted version to 12.0 (API Level 31), I naturally updated my app using target of 12.0, only to realize the app is crashing instantly for all of my Android users now, and since the minimum target is 12.0, I am stuck and have no way to revert. Anyone else having this issue, or any thought on what the issue is?

Comment: have you checked the device logs?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance lol, device logs within VS?

Comment: Android device logs.  Use `adb` (or the Tools in VS)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out after dinner.

Comment: I was finally able to get an error for the crash, which is: **Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:** 'pp.chasemeade.proapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.' - The problem now is I can't find a good example of how ot implement either one....

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+FLAG_IMMUTABLE+or+FLAG_MUTABLE+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out! So, since my app does not utilize PendingIntent, the only way I could be getting that error was from a NuGet Package. It ended up being MarcTron's AdMob Package that was causing it for me. I simply Uninstalled the package, removed whatever was neccessary throughout the Solution and the app is now running with no issue!